# MySQL Connector/C++ PreparedStatement: forward declaration of ‘class sql::PreparedStatement’

Tags: c++, g++, prepared-statement, mysql-connector, forward-declaration

i have "a little" problem with c++ Mysql connector. I wanted use PreparedStatement. I tried  example from documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-prepared-statements.html

I can't compile this code. I still get error:

main.cpp:32:10: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class sql::PreparedStatement’
In file included from /usr/include/mysql_connection.h:28:0,
                 from main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/cppconn/connection.h:44:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class sql::PreparedStatement’

I use debian 7 with g++ 4.7.2.

I've been googling for hours and i have no idea how to solve this problem.
I would be glad for every advice.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    try{
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::PreparedStatement  *prep_stmt;

        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "username", "pass");
        // db name
        con->setSchema("aa");

        prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test(id, name) VALUES (?, ?)");

        // this will couse compilation error
        prep_stmt->setInt(1, 1);

        // this will cause only warning but same message
        delete prep_stmt;

        delete con;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        std::cout << "ERR: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must be missing an include which defines PreparedStatement.

Comment: @polkadotcadaver you are right! Thank you very much I really have no idea how could i missed it. I feel embarrassed. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 14):

One #include is missing, you have to set:

> `#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the linking since either you have not installed the mysql driver, or not added in the compilation command.

You can first install the driver:
***sudo apt-get -y install libmysqlcppconn5 libmysqlcppconn-dev***

Having installed, compile it:
***g++ -o main.cpp -lmysqlcppconn***

Using an IDE, you can follow this link to add the libraries in your IDE.

[MySQL Connector/C++: how to build a client on Linux using NetBeans](http://planet.mysql.com/entry?id=18341)